# Make a div stretch to the right to infinity

Tags: css

i need help with some css

i've made some example site http://gidzior.99k.org/inter/, i want to stretch [aside] background (this with "who are we" text) to the right beyond wrapper which is set to 980px,  i would like to expand [aside] to the right end of the browser window

how to achieve such a thing

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <section id="blog-posts">
            <h2 class="archerBold text-shadow-white pb20">from the blog</h2>
            <article class="blog-post"></article>
            <article class="blog-post"></article>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <section>
                <h2 class="archerBold text-shadow-white pb20">who we are</h2>
            </section>
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#main {
    background: #f8eedf;
    width: 100%;
}
#blog-posts {
    float:left;
    width: 604px;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 0;
}
aside {
    float:left;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 40px;
    width: 354px;
    height: 770px;
    background: #eeddc6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeddc6 0%, #f8edde 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeddc6), color-stop(100%,#f8edde));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeddc6 0%,#f8edde 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeddc6 0%,#f8edde 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeddc6 0%,#f8edde 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeddc6 0%,#f8edde 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeddc6', endColorstr='#f8edde',GradientType=0 );
}
.wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: `right: infinity;` didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your only option is giving your aside `position: absolute;` and then setting `right: 0;` on it .. it'll be on the right-side of the page obviously so you'll need to adjust the right value to your needs as well as the width.

Comment: nope, this is not what i try to do, i would like to expand [aside] to the right end od browser window, not to move it

Comment: position: absolute, left: (to the edge of #blog-posts), width: 1000px

Comment: http://gidzior.99k.org/inter/ look now its perfect, i need to wrap text and it will be ok